# How to comment multiple lines in PhpStorm IDE?

Tags: editor, comments, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm to edit PHP files and configuration files for Apache. How to comment on the selected block and set the symbol comment?
I want,for example,

```
   <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
```

to

```
   #<Directory />
   #    Options FollowSymLinks
   #    AllowOverride None
   #    Order deny,allow
   #    Deny from all
   #</Directory>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Select multiple lines and use the **Comment with Line Comment** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in the default keymap on Windows, can be changed in `Settings | Keymap`).

There is also **Comment with Block Comment** that works for file types that have special style comment for code blocks (not applicable for .htaccess).

Comment: `Command`+`/` on a mac (well, i am using ideavim key mapping, so it might be different)

Comment: since my macbook does have `/` on the `7`. I had to use `command`+`-` by default. But if shortcuts are not working, go to shortcuts settings and try it out there, it will show you how your pressed keys are getting interpreteded.

Answer (score 21):

There are two possibilities (in cases where block of comment are available like php, json etc files)

First 
Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
 
Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

will produce

```
// comment
```

Second 
Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> 
Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

will produce

```
/* comment */
```

Comment: Exactly this I was searching . Thanks, @Dawid.

Answer (score 5):

For European keyboard you need to add a new shortcut:

1. Go to `Preferences > Keymap`
2. Here search for "comment"
3. Right click on your action (ie. "Comment with line comment") and choose `Add keyboard shortcut`
4. Now digit on keyboard your wanted shortcut  (for Mac `CMD + SHIFT + 7`) and OK, that's it

Answer (score 0):

in mac :

```
block some lines of codes
command + /
```