# Comments Only in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there anyway to add comments that are visible ONLY in PhpStorm?

It's not an issue in php files, but would be great to comment some development info in HTML or JS files which should only be visible to developers.

Comment: AFAIK -- No. Few ideas though: for HTML you may use template engines (e.g. Twig etc) and use its comment feature; for JavaScript -- minify final code; it will remove all dev comments.

Comment: I think this link might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407481/how-to-comment-multiple-lines-in-phpstorm-ide

Comment: Can you explain that further? As both HTML and JS are served directly to the browser without further processing, how should this be possible?

Comment: @NicoHaase If you use a template/minify engine you are not serving HTML/JS directly to the browser. That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer of your questing lies in the question itself. You want to make comments in HTML and JS files, but you do not want them to be shown to the public.
In this case you must make some compilation of those files and remove the comments.
There is a such tool developed already and it is called Webpack.

Here is the link to [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts)

This will not only remove your comments, but compile and minify any js code you throw at him.